# Setting a new View on Button Click Event

Tags: android, android-layout

i just started learning the android app development. I want to set another view on button event. how can i do that.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //  b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

}
public void call_it(Menu v)
{
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_);
}
```

Comment: Set a view? Means start a new activity? Or display any view in same activity? And share your code that you tried

Comment: i want to display a new view or layout in same activity.

Comment: u just visible in layout on ur button click ...

Comment: i tried both setView(...) and setContentView(....). but it crashed with"Your App Has Stopped."

Comment: public void call_it(Menu v)
    {
      //setView(R.layout.activity_new_);
         //setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_);
    }

Comment: Please post your code and logcat output, so all can have a look at it and tell you where is a mistake

Comment: Do you want activity_main's view after button click, too? Or you can start a new activity.

Comment: yeah i want that view too.

Comment: Check the edited answer. You have to use inflation. If you find any problem, tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inflate it from some xml, you can follow this:

Inside your `onCreate()` find your layout's view as following:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayoutid);
```

Here `mylayoutid` would be the id of outer most layout of your `activity_main.xml` in which you want to add new layout/view.
And then button click function would be as following:

```
public void call_it(Menu v)
{
    final LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) linflater .inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_new, null);
    myLayout.addView(lLayout)
}
```

If you want to create a new view and show it, you can do as:

```
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayourParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayourParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
txt .setLayoutParams(lp);
txt .setTextSize(10);
myLayout.addView(txt);
```

Comment: Thanks Shreya, but its my 2nd day in Android SDK.

Comment: @user2071323 Do one thing. Edit your question with your code and logcat output. It will be much better for others to understand problem and suggest a solution.

Comment: @HarvantS. Done? Or still some issue?